# Recyclerview blinking when scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am showing images from server in **RecylerView**. When i use fix size of **ImageView** or **layout**, it works fine.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:clipToPadding="false">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/thumb_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

But when I set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, all image blinking.I cant set fix size cause my all images are different.
I'm loading image to imageview with glide.
Here is my BindViewHolder code-

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            Photos image = imagesList.get(position);
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(image.getThumb())
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {


                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            ((MyViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(((MyViewHolder) holder).imageView);
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new 
            View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mListener.onClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
```

}

Below image is taken from somewhere. My problem is something like this. Image blink like this but it doesn't get mix. One image flicker on it's imageview.
Adapter Class

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private Context mContext;
private ClickListener mListener;
private final ArrayList<Photos> imagesList;

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ClickListener mListener;
    TextView image_date, image_weight, imageHit;
    ImageView imageView, sudoImage;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    public MyViewHolder(View view, ClickListener listener) {
        super(view);

        mListener = listener;
        image_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_date);
        image_weight = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_weight);
        imageHit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hit);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_image);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarThumb);
    }
}

public static class ViewHolderAdMob extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public AdView mAdView;

    public ViewHolderAdMob(View view) {
        super(view);
        MainActivity.loadAd(view);
    }
}

public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Photos> images, ClickListener listener) {
    mContext = context;
    this.imagesList = images;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position % 8 == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case 1:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.util_list_item_admob, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolderAdMob(v);

        default:
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.util_image_thumb, parent, false);

            return new MyViewHolder(itemView, mListener);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case 1:

            break;

        default:
            final Photos image = imagesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Glide.with(mContext)
                            .load(image.getThumb())
                            .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                                @Override
                                public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    return false;
                                }

                            })
                            .fitCenter()
                            .into(((MyViewHolder) holder).imageView);
                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).image_date.setText(image.getTitle());
                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).imageHit.setText(image.getHit());
                    ((MyViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            mListener.onClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                    });

                    if (!image.getWeight().isEmpty()) {
                        ((MyViewHolder) holder).image_weight.setText(image.getWeight() + " gm");
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imagesList.size();
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(int position);
}
```

}

Activity class-

public class DJPhotos extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String url = "http://192.168.43.238/";
//   private static final String url = "https://desijewel.in/";
private static final String script = url + "android/android_script.php";
static final String REQ_TAG = "VACTIVITY";
public ArrayList<Photos> imagelist;
// Variable for pagination
private int pageNumber = 1;
private boolean isLoading = true;
private int pastVisibleItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount, previousTotal = 0;
private int viewThesold = 0;
RecycleViewAdapter adapter;
String table, type, weightFrom, weightTo;
Button filterButton;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ProgressBar progressBar, progressBarBottom;

RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
boolean isFirstTime = true;
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_djphotos);
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBarBottom = findViewById(R.id.progressBarBottom);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    table = intent.getStringExtra("table");
    type = intent.getStringExtra("type");
    weightFrom = intent.getStringExtra("weightFrom");
    weightTo = intent.getStringExtra("weightTo");
    imagelist = new ArrayList<>();
    TextView desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);
    filterButton = findViewById(R.id.filterButton);
    filterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(v);
        }
    });

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    RecycleViewAdapter.ClickListener listener = new RecycleViewAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            bundle.putSerializable("url", imagelist);//And here i'm always getting the latest image list . u
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            Full_Image newFragment = Full_Image.newInstance();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");
        }
    };

    adapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(DJPhotos.this, imagelist, listener);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisibleItems = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            if (dy > 0) {
                if (isLoading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                        isLoading = false;
                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    }
                }
                if (!isLoading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount - 10) <= (pastVisibleItems + viewThesold)) {
                    performPagination();
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    getJsonResponsePost();
}

public void getJsonResponsePost() {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("table", table);
    params.put("weightFrom", weightFrom);
    params.put("weightTo", weightTo);
    params.put("type", type);
    HashMap hash = new HashMap();
    hash.put("page", pageNumber);
    params.putAll(hash);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, script, json,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    pageNumber++;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    imagelist.clear();
                    JSONArray heroArray = null;
                    try {
                        heroArray = response.getJSONArray("images");
                        for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Photos photos = new Photos();
                            photos.setUrl(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                            photos.setThumb(jsonObject.getString("thumb"));
                            photos.setWeight(jsonObject.getString("weight"));
                            photos.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("image_title"));
                            photos.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                            photos.setHit(jsonObject.getString("hit"));
                            imagelist.add(photos);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
    jsonObjectRequest.setTag(REQ_TAG);
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

}

public String getTableValue() {
    return table;
}

public void showDialog(View v) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    CustomDialog customDialog = new CustomDialog();

    customDialog.show(manager, "Custom");
}

public void performPagination() {

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("table", table);
    params.put("weightFrom", weightFrom);
    params.put("weightTo", weightTo);
    params.put("type", type);
    HashMap hash = new HashMap();
    hash.put("page", pageNumber);
    params.putAll(hash);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, script, json,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    pageNumber++;
                    progressBarBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if(imagelist == null)
                        imagelist = new ArrayList<>();
                    JSONArray heroArray = null;


                    try {
                        heroArray = response.getJSONArray("images");
                        for (int i = 0; i < heroArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = heroArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Photos photos = new Photos();
                            photos.setUrl(jsonObject.getString("image"));
                            photos.setThumb(jsonObject.getString("thumb"));
                            photos.setWeight(jsonObject.getString("weight"));
                            photos.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("image_title"));
                            photos.setDate(jsonObject.getString("date"));
                            photos.setHit(jsonObject.getString("hit"));
                            imagelist.add(photos);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


        }
    });
    jsonObjectRequest.setTag(REQ_TAG);
    jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

Comment: Can you please add gif or something to understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Photos image = imagesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(image.getThumb())
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            ((MyViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(((MyViewHolder) holder).imageView);

        }
    });
    ((MyViewHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mListener.onClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumb_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Glide are take some time to load image but you can store image as catch in glide then again don't take time to load image..

define this code into adapter..

```
  Glide.with(context).load(CommonUtils.checkForNullValue(userData.getUserVo().getPhoto())).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.big_user))
                .into(holder.ivUserImage);
```

and also image quality depended.

Comment: i added Glide code but glide take some time to load image but you can store image into catch using this line                  .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
   after that it not load again and again it fetch image from catch.

Comment: provided your full adapter and activity class code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

> UIL aims to provide a powerful, flexible and highly customizable instrument for image loading, caching and displaying. It provides a lot of configuration options and good control over the image loading and caching process.

It provides many features such as:

1. Multithread image loading (async or sync)
2. Wide customization of ImageLoader's configuration (thread executors, downloader, decoder, memory and disk cache, display image options, etc.)
3. Many customization options for every display image call (stub images, caching switch, decoding options, Bitmap processing and displaying, etc.)
4. Image caching in memory and/or on disk (device's file system or SD card)
5. Listening loading process (including downloading progress)

Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Problem is with not with glide. It works fine when layout_height is fixed.